# After Unity build the game it cannot read CSV files from Resources folder

Tags: unity-game-engine

I develop a game that reads, constantly, multiple datasets from a subfolder in the Assets/Resources folder of Unity.

While in the development mode the game works fine, when I build the game (I tried in all platforms - Mac OS, Windows x 86_64, Windows 86, WebGL) it seems that it cannot read the CSV files from the resource folder and does not behave as expected. The size of the Resources file is not large (7MB).

Is there any restriction in loading files from the Resources folder in build mode?

I load the CSVs with `Resources.Load<TextAsset>("folder/" + dataset);`

Comment: maybe the build is in another path and you are using relative paths to find your files?

Comment: I load the datasets with the Resources.Load<TextAsset>("folder/" + dataset) which I suppose is by default a relative path, that Unity, during built time should convert it in absolute path.

Comment: I would share how the `dataset` path is retrieved in the code. It does not make much sense that it does not work only in build but maybe some expert eye has something to say.

Comment: Also I would check the [LogFiles](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/LogFiles.html) of the build execution to check what is returned at the resources load step...

Answer (score 0):

It is better to put the entire path of .csv file!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).